# What is the best, cleanest and shortest way to check if a given value is valid URL when working with models?

Tags: python, django, url, url-validation

I rather want to use Django's built-in functionalities as much as possible and avoid implementing stuff myself as much as possible!

Why doesn't the following code issue exceptions when given a non-URL value?

**models.py**:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.db import models

class Snapshot(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(validators=[URLValidator])
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Snapshot

def index(request):
    a = Snapshot(url='gott ist tot')
    a.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this validator is run when you use a django form.
More information about validators on the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/

if you do a form :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Snapshot

class SnshotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snapshot
        fields = ('url', )
```

and your views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SnapshotForm

def index(request):
    a = SnapshotForm(data={'url': 'gott ist tot'})
    if a .is_valid()
        a.save()
    else:
        print(a.errors)
```

Your validator will be run and you will see the errors form message

Without using form, you can call manually validator in your view or in the save method:

```
# in views
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def index(request):
    url_validator = URLValidator()
    url = 'gott ist tot'

    is_valid_url = False
    try:
        url_validator(url)
    except ValidationError:
       pass

    if is_valid_url:
        a = Snapshot(url=url)
        a.save()
    else:
        print(a.errors)
```

Be careful ! I do not recommanded to bypass the validator with forms, i think it is the better way for maximizing usage of django builtins funtions

Comment: What should I do if I don't wanted to utilize forms?

Comment: i edited my solution. Be care if you want to use the solution with save method. The manager create method can alos create object without use the save method, so you need to duplicate code in this case. I think usage of forms is the better solution

Comment: I don't understand , plz explain it differently

Comment: Model.objects.create(...) create object without call model.save() so if you want to check url with validator on saving object, you have to make this check in the managers of your model and in the save method of your model. But i repeat, the good way with django and the MVT pattern is to use the Form class